# Data fetching not works just on mobile in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch

This is a simple fetching data on a component. It works like a charm on desktop browser, but on mobile browsers the fetcher raises error!

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export default function Test() {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get('https://dummyjson.com/products');
        setData(data.products);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('fetch error', error);
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Data', data);   
  }, [data]);

  return <>{data && data[0]?.title}</>;
}
```

**Error** will show when I remove the try catch block, so I can't log it to the terminal.

[image]

Comment: What's the error? Add it to post.

Comment: Just a tip for you. It's not recommended to to fetch inside a useEffect. Instead next.js recommends to use a package like [SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/) or [react-query](https://tanstack.com/query/v3/)

Comment: @FelixEklöf thank you. Firstly I have used SWR that has the above result, then change it to useEffct to solve the problem but noting got chaned.